# ODE particular solution (physics)

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations, physics

I have to do this exercise:
[image]

($Z(t)=I(t)$, it's printed wrong).

I have a doubt about the first item. To find all resonance when $R=1$, I found the particular solution $I_{p}(t)=A\sin(\omega t)+B\cos(\omega t)$.

I got the first and second derivates
$$I_{p}'=A\omega\cos(\omega t)-B\omega\sin(\omega t)$$
$$I_{p}''=-A\omega^{2}\sin(\omega t)-B\omega^{2}\cos(\omega t)$$
then, when I substitute in the equation
$$I''(t)+I'(t)+I(t)=\sin(\omega t)$$
I got the system on $(A,B)$:
$$\left\{\begin{array}{l}
-A\omega^{2}-B\omega+A=1 \\
-B\omega^{2}+A\omega+B=0
\end{array}\right.$$
so
$$A=\frac{(1-\omega^{2})}{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}$$
I calculated $A$ because it follows $\sin(\omega t)$ and with this I can find all resonance frequencies.

Well, to find them, I gotta find the values of $\omega$ which makes $A$ as large as possible. To $A\to+\infty$, so, its denominator must goes to 0:
$$(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}\to0$$
But that's not possible.

The answer is $\displaystyle\frac{1}{2\pi\sqrt{2}}$. Comparing with the exercise, I know that $\omega=1/\sqrt{2}$.

If the denominator was $(1-\omega^{2})^{2}-\omega^{2}$, I got the result, but I don't know what's wrong here.

**EDIT:** I found after
$$I_{p}(t)=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}}\sin(\omega t-\alpha)$$
where $\alpha=\arctan(\omega/(1-\omega^{2})$. So,
$$A=\frac{1}{\sqrt{(1-\omega^{2})^{2}+\omega^{2}}}$$
and it's large just if its denominator is small... but how?!

Comment: This was cross-posted to Physics (where it is on hold as of the writing of this comment): http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/125897/ode-envolving-current

Comment: This is obviously homework, but I'll give you a hint: the solution is a superposition of two solutions, a particular integral and the complementary function (the solution to the homogeneous part).